# JavaScript Mootools facebook like link preview (grabber) library

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, mootools

Does anyone knows **link preview (grabber) library similar to Facebook** as shown in the following image. Mainly it should identify the URL type (whether it's a YouTube, Vimeo or ect) embed attachments from the URL.

[image: It should embed attachments from the URL]

A Mootools library would be my preference. But jQuery would be also acceptable.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Found this jQuery library

http://lab.leocardz.com/facebook-link-preview-php--jquery/

but looking for a mootools library